# Who is the caller of a private Rails method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, private

Who is the caller inside the `call_say_koan` method? Is it the class `Koan`, `self`, or an instance of `Koan`?

```
class Koan
  def call_say_koan
    say_koan
  end

  private
    def say_koan
      puts "What is the sound of one hand clapping?"
    end
end
```

Comment: The caller is `call_say_koan`, using the standard definition of "caller", unless you have severely redefined what the word "caller" means, in which case you should provide your definition.

Answer (score 3):

How long to shave a yak?

What color is your bike shed?

Ah young padawan, the answer is axiomatic.

That which is shown to all may be called by any.

That which is hidden from all may only be called by self.

Who is the caller of say_koan?

It is the instance of Koan called self.

What color is *your* parachute?

Comment: No, it must be `self`, not just any instance. Namaste.

Comment: When you say `Koan.new.say_koan`, you are not the instance of Koan. You are Cary. And you are not new Koan. So, you may not call `say_koan`. You may, perhaps, say `say_cary`. But that is not for us to know. Because what is private to you is private to you.

Comment: I somehow missed that the private method was being called from the public one, but `self` is of course the same within both methods, namely an instance of the class.

Comment: Not just any instance. `self` is `self`. `other` is `other`. Only the instance `self` can call `say_koan`.

Comment: how `Koan.new.say_koan` not new Koan?

Comment: When stackjlei type 'Koan.new.say_koan` then it is *stackjlei* who say `say_koan`. stacklei is not `Koan.new` stacklei is stacklei. `Koan.new` is `Koan.new`. Only `Koan.new` may say `say_koan`. Not stacklei. stacklei may say `say_stacklei` is stacklei like.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the methods of classes are defined with the prefix 'self.', and every other method is an instance one. So, the caller is an instance of Koan.